# Dynamic Google Parner Logo not loading in production (build)

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby

We are trying to load the Google Partner Logo dynamically (per request from Google) on a Gatsby site. The logo is basically just a div that loads som styling and an iframe, after the google script is loaded/accepted på the api. The logo loads fine in development but is very unstable in the build (1/10 times).

I tried loading the script in React Helmet directly in the component and directly on the page. In Helmet the scripts load every time and return no error, but somehow the logo-div receives a crazy stying and the iframe doesn't load at all.

We double checked the acces in our google account and that is 100% correct, so my guess is that something happens in the build...

```js
// from helmet component
import React from "react"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"

function SEO({ description, lang, meta, title }) {
  <Helmet>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer</script>
  </Helmet>
  // ... a lot of irelevant SEO stuff excluded
}

export default SEO
```

```
// from google logo component
import React from "react"

const FeaturedCompanies = () => {
return <div className="g-partnersbadge" data-agency-id="1850113825"></div>
}

export default FeaturedCompanies
```

Comment: Please include your code as text in the question, that way it shows in search and members seeking can help you can copy/paste your code if needed. Please consider: [discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Sure, absolutely!